# How to fix errors caused by two identical jar with the same name but different versions?

Tags: maven, consul

In the project, there are two modules: data and infrastructure.

1. Data module uses the grpc plug-in provided by Google: grpc-protobuf, which refers to com.google.guava:guava [version:26.0-android].
2. Infrastructure module uses consul's plug-in: consul-client, which refers to com.google.guava:guava [version:22.0].

And the data module depends on the Infrastructure module.

There is no problem at compile time, but at run time, ConsulCache in consul-client calls the Stopwatch.elapsed() method in com.google.guava:guava, which is no-argument in com.google.guava:guava:22.0 and parametric in com.google.guava:guava:26.0-android. ConsulCache always points to com.google.guava:guava:26.0-android rather than com.goog.guava:guava:22.0, which will report the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.elapsed()Ljava/time/Duration;
at com.orbitz.consul.cache.ConsulCache$1.onComplete(ConsulCache.java:103)
```

Because it's a maven project and it's all about automatically managing jar packages, it's automatically referenced by third-party plug-ins themselves.

How to fix this exception without modifying their source code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to decide if you want version `22.0` or version `26.0-android`.

Then you add a `<dependencyManagment>` entry to the poms (or the common parent pom, even better) that manages `com.google.guava:guava` to the version you want.

The dependencyManagement (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) overwrites all transitively found version numbers of that dependency. So you only get the version you choose.

Comment: Data module needs 26.0-android and Infrastructure module needs 22, both of which are indispensable. So...T.T

Comment: You mean to say add <dependencyManagment> to every sub-module? eg. data, Infrastructure?  I only add<dependencyManagment> to root-module.

Comment: @realvie Do you run the Data Module and the Infrastructure module in different JVMs? Otherwise you need to decide. You can have only one versions of a given library in one JVM.

Comment: Then you need to figure out a version that works with both. If this is not possible, you can try to rename packages with the maven shade plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/ (I have never tried that myself).